# Numbering Image List in Gallery

Tags: shortcode, gallery

While adding images in a post with the gallery shortcode, I want to display an image number as title of the image e.g if there are 3 images in a gallery and displayed as a list, above each image there should be a serial number.

Shown as 
[image]

I can set it afterwards with inline css. I tried alot in `media.php`, but without success.

Comment: Never really a good idea to hack core files.

Comment: You cannot change the meaning of a question after there are answers. Including a featured image is a new question. It requires specific information about the loop and the placement of that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a custom function between the gallery shortcode handler and the output. Catch the `img` elements and add a static counter. Then return the gallery output to WordPress.

Sample code:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_74492_replace_gallery_shortcode' );

/**
 * Replace the default shortcode handlers.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpse_74492_replace_gallery_shortcode()
{
    remove_shortcode( 'gallery' );
    add_shortcode( 'gallery', 'wpse_74492_gallery_shortcode' );
}

function wpse_74492_gallery_shortcode( $attr )
{
    // Let WordPress create the regular gallery …
    $gallery = gallery_shortcode( $attr );

    $gallery = preg_replace_callback( '~<img~', 'wpse_74492_gallery_callback', $gallery );

    return $gallery;
}

function wpse_74492_gallery_callback( $matches )
{
    static $count = 0;
    $count += 1;

    return "<span class='gallery-number'>$count</span>" . $matches[0];
}
```

This will insert a `<span class='gallery-number'>1</span>` into the link. You can position it in CSS with:

```
.gallery-number 
{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 1em;
}
```

Comment: where should I add this, media.php or functions.php?

Comment: Your theme’s `functions.php`. The `media.php` is a core file, it will be overwritten during the next WordPress update.

Comment: What does this mean?? wpse_74492_replace_gallery_shortcode
Change it with?

Comment: You can copy the code as it is to the `functions.php` I have tested it, it works. The naming scheme we use here is `wpse` for WordPress Stack Exchange plus the question number as prefix to avoid collisions with other people’s code.

Comment: Works fine, but it doesn't show count on featured image.

Comment: Of course it doesn’t. Your question was about the gallery? That is something completely different.

Comment: Is it possible with featured too?

Comment: I have no idea why and how you want to number something that can exist just once per post. Please ask a new question for that.

Comment: No, I want to say that the numbering should start with featured image as one, continue counting with the gallery images as it is doing above. Just show featured image as one and gallery images starting with two.